# Custom products attributes stopped updating from dashboard or programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, product-attribute

So, on this Magento 1 instance, everything worked fine until a couple of months ago.

I have approx 20 custom attributes attached to an attribute set for a Product. Two of them are not saving. If change the value and click save it says *Product has been saved* but the value is the same.

I've tried reindexing, disable the cache and save them programmatically, nothing works anymore. If I create new attributes, they are not saving either.

How can I fix this as these attributes were working before.?